# Select start/end dates two tables SQL

Tags: php, mysql

I have two tables table1 and table2 in both contains data and column named timestamp

table1

```
| id |     name   |       timestamp     |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 |     Paul   | 2018-01-01 12:43:11 |
|  2 |     Mike   | 2018-01-07 10:13:22 |
|  3 |     Bob    | 2018-01-27 17:11:53 |
|  4 |     John   | 2018-01-15 09:08:47 |
```

table2

```
| id |     name   |       timestamp     |
---------------------------------------------
|  1 |     David  | 2018-02-01 12:43:11 |
|  2 |     Alesha | 2018-02-07 10:13:22 |
|  3 |     Smith  | 2018-03-05 17:11:53 |
|  4 |     Troy   | 2018-04-15 09:08:47 |
```

Lets say the selected date are

```
$from = 2018-01-01 00:00:00
$to = 2018-02-08 23:59:59
```

How to make a one time SQL to show the all data in both SQL ?
So the request would be

```
|  1 |     Paul   | 2018-01-01 12:43:11 |
|  2 |     Mike   | 2018-01-07 10:13:22 |
|  3 |     Bob    | 2018-01-27 17:11:53 |
|  4 |     John   | 2018-01-15 09:08:47 |
|  1 |     David  | 2018-02-01 12:43:11 |
|  2 |     Alesha | 2018-02-07 10:13:22 |
```

Please note the $from and $to values could exist in one table only like if

```
$from = 2018-03-01 00:00:00
$to = 2018-03-06 23:59:59
```

Result will show

```
|  3 |     Smith  | 2018-03-05 17:11:53 |
```

I tried this SQL but its not working

```
 SELECT * `FROM table1.table2` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'
```

Comment: Well \`obviously this\` is not \`working\` !!

Comment: `SELECT * \`FROM table1.table2\` WHERE` doesn't look quite right =)

Comment: `$from = 2018-03-01 00:00:00
$to = 2018-03-06 23:59:59` - please use the proper syntax here, there should be quotes around those and closure.

Comment: See: [Why should I provide an MCVE for what seems to me to be a very simple SQL query?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-an-mcve-for-what-seems-to-me-to-be-a-very-simple-sql-query)

Comment: @Hex `BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to'` is valid.

Comment: I believe you need [`UNION`](http://www.mysqltutorial.org/sql-union-mysql.aspx).

Comment: I'd probably do two separate select statements and union them together as @ PM 77-1 mentioned. `Select * from table1... UNION ALL  Select * from table2...` while using a union to join them into one return.

Comment: With UNION ALL it shows 
Syntax error

Comment: Try a normal Union instead.

Answer (score 0):

Something like the following might work:

```
(SELECT `id`, `name`, `timestamp` FROM `table1` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')
UNION
(SELECT `id`, `name`, `timestamp` FROM `table2` WHERE `timestamp` BETWEEN '$from' AND '$to')
```

As suggested in the comments to your question, this uses the SQL [UNION](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/union.html) command to return the union of two different SELECT statements. Note that this requires both SELECT statements to return the same number/types of columns.